# change an icon of an installed application using xamarin

Tags: file, xamarin

I want to change the icon and the name of an existing application installed on the device. would be ideal if the application icon could somehow be hidden.

the project I am working on is using a secondary application that I do not want the user to see. only my application should be able to launch it.

but I figured I would have a better chance just changing the icon to something similar to my application.

is any of this possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you do an update to the application it's straightforward to change in your application file. Do you mean you want to change the icon remotely without a redeploy? (It seems like an update could be easier).

In terms of the secondary application, can you give more details on what you're using it for? If you're doing Android development, for example, if you're just using this to do a background task and the user never interacts with it it seems like moving this to a service could be ideal.